# jquery is not working in my php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I just tried to make a show hide div using jquery. It was working good with HTML but when I change it to PHP, the click event is not working!

In my college project I tried to make a `div` show and hide using jquery. It works on HTML correctly when I change the extension to PHP it is not working. I am not an expert in programming so any one please help

Here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['username'])||empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
    header('location://localhost/kcp/admin_login.php');
    exit();

}
else
{
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="show.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><input type="button" value="Case view" id="caseli"/></li>
   <li><input type="button" value="User Managment" id="userli"/></li>
   <li><input type="button" value="Messages" id="messageli"/></li>
   <li><input type="button" value="Logout" id="logoutli"/></li>
  </ul>


 </div>
 <div class="main">

 <div class="case">
  <?php
  //require case.php;
  ?>
  <p>this is case</p>
 </div>
 <div class="user">
  <?php
  //require usermanage.php;
  ?>
  <p>this is user</p>
 </div>
 <div class="message">
  <?php
  //require message.php;
  ?>
 <p>this is message</p>
 </div>
 <div class="logout">
  <?php
  //require logout.php;
  ?>
  <p>this is logout</p>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

here is my show.js code

```
 // JavaScript Document
$('#messageli').click(function()
{
    $('.case').hide();
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.logout').hide();
    $('.message').show();

});
$('#caseli').click(function()
{
    $('.case').show();
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.logout').hide();
    $('.message').gide();

});
$('#userli').click(function()
{
    $('.case').hide();
    $('.user').show();
    $('.logout').hide();
    $('.message').hide();

});
$('#logoutli').click(function()
{
    $('.case').hide();
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.logout').show();
    $('.message').hide();

});
```

Comment: Did you wrapped js code into `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code */ });`

Comment: Can you please paste your full javascript code hete?

Comment: Just a little note: each time you click on #messageli, #caseli, #userli or #logoutli, jQuery will look for all the .case, .user, .logout, .message elements in the DOM. So, it might be smarter to store the result of each in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make use of delegated method calling in jquery and get code parsed only after all `DOM` element parsed in HTML as follows-

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    $(document).on('click','#messageli',function()
    {
        $('.case').hide();
        $('.user').hide();
        $('.logout').hide();
        $('.message').show();

    });
    $(document).on('click','#caseli',function()
    {
        $('.case').show();
        $('.user').hide();
        $('.logout').hide();
        $('.message').gide();

    });
    $(document).on('click','#userli',function()
    {
        $('.case').hide();
        $('.user').show();
        $('.logout').hide();
        $('.message').hide();

    });
    $(document).on('click','#logoutli',function()
    {
        $('.case').hide();
        $('.user').hide();
        $('.logout').show();
        $('.message').hide();

    }); 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are including jQuery file in the top of your web page while trying to access DOM elements you have two solution

1. move the jQuery including script to the bottom of your body tag or keep the script in head section.
2. wrap all your function in `document.ready` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('#messageli').click(function() {
    $('.case').hide();
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.logout').hide();
    $('.message').show();

});
$('#caseli').click(function()   {
    $('.case').show();
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.logout').hide();
    $('.message').gide();

});
$('#userli').click(function()  {
    $('.case').hide();
    $('.user').show();
    $('.logout').hide();
    $('.message').hide();

});
$('#logoutli').click(function() {
    $('.case').hide();
    $('.user').hide();
    $('.logout').show();
    $('.message').hide();

});
})
```

Comment: thank you sir it works. could you please give more info about that

Comment: Think of it as if your script tag is jus like any other HTML tag will load according to its order, so when you put your script tag at the top it will load and execute at first and because you are trying to access `$('#messageli')` which is not loaded yet it will fail. so the solution is to load your script just after the DOM elements or to use  `$(document).ready` which will fire after loading the DOM elements

Answer (score 1):

JQuery code is not working because script fires when elements not even rendered. Use ready function or include js file in footer. you can use ready function like this

```
jQuery(function(){
   //your code here
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to write the events inside the ready function. Then only th jquery can call the curresponding listeners rapidly.

So please try like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#messageli').click(function() {
        $('.case').hide();
        $('.user').hide();
        $('.logout').hide();
        $('.message').show();
    });
    $('#caseli').click(function() {
        $('.case').show();
        $('.user').hide();
        $('.logout').hide();
        $('.message').gide();
    });
    $('#userli').click(function() {
        $('.case').hide();
        $('.user').show();
        $('.logout').hide();
        $('.message').hide();
    });
    $('#logoutli').click(function() {
        $('.case').hide();
        $('.user').hide();
        $('.logout').show();
        $('.message').hide();
    });
})
</script>
```